# Html generator breaking php code

Tags: php, html

I have a cool html generator that generates html from a drag and drop interface. I have tried to customise it by adding some simple php to it for form validation. The problem I am having is that when I click "Get HTML" it changes my php code from:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
```

to something like

```
<form method="post" action="<?&lt echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);&gt>">
```

Is there a way to get it to show the html without messing up the php? It seems to just change the php tags themselves.

Comment: html != php. if the generator isn't php-aware, it'll treat the php as invalid/broken html.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to change that easily or is it very complicated?

Comment: What program are you using?

Comment: Well, it's not a program actually. It's a HTML theme I downloaded from Theme Forest.

Comment: You cannot execute server-side code (PHP) in the client-side (Javascript).

Comment: Okay, so you are saying what I am trying to do is impossible?

Comment: Could I use html_entity_decode()   ?